# Simple RSVP form validation through JavaScript, jQuery or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am developing what I thought was a very simple RSVP form for a wedding website on Wordpress. Data will be transferred to the site administrator through email, so no need to mess with a database.

I've used these tutorials for validating/sanitizing input using PHP. As a newbie, they've both left me stumped.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/custom-php-contact-forms/
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/

I'm starting to wonder if there's an easier way, e.g., through JavaScript. If so, I was wondering about the benefits of using PHP over JavaScript and vice versa for form validation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there's a "benefit" to one over the other. Honestly, you should do both. The javascript validation in order to show the user that he / she entered an input incorrectly, and on the server side to check, just in case, they didn't somehow submit an incorrect login.

However, out of the two, the server-side is definitely the required one. So if you need to pick one over the other, do server-side. The reason that server-side is better than front-end in this sense is because the user can't tamper with the server-side: that is all your code. The only thing they can do is send in inputs.